# ado.net XO game

Tags: c#, ado.net

i wrote a code that inserting the players names, now at the end of the game i want to update the scores to +1 to the winner (under winnings column) and +1 to the loser (under losses column)

i get every time an error : Incorrect syntax near '(' .

first insert code:
            int readtable = 0;

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection
        (@"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=ExampleDB;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand tryfindname = new SqlCommand();
        tryfindname.Connection = con;
        tryfindname.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        tryfindname.CommandText = "select * from XOhalloffame where PlayerName='@input1'";
        tryfindname.Parameters.AddWithValue("@input1", player1.getname());

        SqlDataReader readingtime = tryfindname.ExecuteReader();
        while (readingtime.Read())
        {
            readtable = 1;
        }
        con.Close();

        if (readtable == 0)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand pl1db = new SqlCommand();
            pl1db.Connection = con;
            pl1db.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            pl1db.CommandText = "insert into XOhalloffame (PlayerName ,Winnings, Losses) values (@name1, @win1, @lose1)";
            pl1db.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name1",player1.getname());
            pl1db.Parameters.AddWithValue("@win1", 0);
            pl1db.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lose1", 0);
            pl1db.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlCommand pl2db = new SqlCommand();
            pl2db.Connection = con;
            pl1db.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            pl2db.CommandText = "insert into XOhalloffame (PlayerName ,Winnings, Losses) values (@name2, @win2, @lose2)";
            pl2db.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name2",player2.getname());
            pl2db.Parameters.AddWithValue("@win2", 0);
            pl2db.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lose2", 0);
            pl2db.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
```

the problematic code:

```
    public void whowon()
    {
        if (turn == 1)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(),
            "success", "setInterval(2000);alert('Player X wins !!!');", true);



            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection
            (@"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=ExampleDB;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand wincmd = new SqlCommand();
            wincmd.Connection = con;
            wincmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            wincmd.CommandText = "update XOhalloffame set (Winnings='@win1'+1,) where (PlayerName='"+player1.getname()+"')";
            wincmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@win1",+1);
            wincmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me you should have different tables for Players Details and Games Played. 
Say one table is Player_Master containing player_id(PK), player_name and second table Say Game_Master containing player1_id(FK), player2_id(FK), winning_player_id where data will be inserted each time new game is played.
You can modify table schema according to your use.